# Jboss Web Service:Error :java.io.IOException: Could not transmit message

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jboss

Hi I am trying to deploy a web service client application in Jboss 4.2.3GA. I already did this and it works in glassfish v2.x. I copied jboss-saaj.jar, jboss-jaxws-ext.jar, jboss-jaxws.jar, jboss-jaxrpc.jar and jaxb-api.jar. Can someone please shed some info?

Also I deployed this in netbeans 6.7.

```
# Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not transmit message  
# at org.jboss.ws.core.client.RemotingConnectionImpl.invoke(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:204)  
# at org.jboss.ws.core.client.SOAPRemotingConnection.invoke(SOAPRemotingConnection.java:77)  
# at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:337)  
# at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.CallImpl.invokeInternal(CallImpl.java:517)  
# ... 4 more  
# Caused by: org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: Can not connect http client invoker.  
# at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.useHttpURLConnection(HTTPClientInvoker.java:333)  
# at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.transport(HTTPClientInvoker.java:135)  
# at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:122)  
# at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1634)  
# at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:548)  
# at org.jboss.ws.core.client.RemotingConnectionImpl.invoke(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:183)  
# ... 7 more  
# Caused by: org.jboss.ws.WSException: Invalid HTTP server response [404] - Not Found  
# at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPMessageUnMarshaller.read(SOAPMessageUnMarshaller.java:77)  
# at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.readResponse(HTTPClientInvoker.java:473)  
# at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.useHttpURLConnection(HTTPClientInvoker.java:305)  
# ... 12 more
```

I tried with version 4.2.2 GA by copying jboss-saaj.jar and jboss-jaxrpc.jar to /lib/endorsement and it works. But I also tried with version 5.1.0GA and it didn't work there.

To make things easy, here is what I would like help in. If anyone has deployed web services in jboss and had to copy jars to certain folders can you please let me know what you did? I would prefer if you used 4.3.3GA or 5.1.0GA. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

You can also configure the **chunksize** for your instance at

> SERVER_HOME/SERVER_PROFILE/deployers/jbossws.deployer/META-INF/standard-jaxws-client-config.xml

Change

```
<property-value>2048</property-value>
```

to

```
<property-value>0</property-value>
```

for property

```
    <client-config>
        <config-name>Standard Client</config-name>
        <feature>http://org.jboss.ws/dispatch/validate</feature>
        <property>
           <property-name>http://org.jboss.ws/http#chunksize</property-name>
        </property>
    </client-config>
```

See http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Workaroundwhenchunkedencodingisnotsupported for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also having this problem on JBoss 5.0.1. I have copied jbossws-*.jars into lib endorsed also and I reference this when I run junits and it works fine. However when I use my client from within a running JBoss AS I get this : Caused by: org.jboss.ws.WSException: Invalid HTTP server response [404] - Not Found But I've triple checked that the service endpoint I have configured is correct, I can go to it in a browser, soapUI can hit it, and my unit test using same client can call it.

AFter much research I found that JBoss (and JBossWS) may have some bugs in the JBossWS 3.0.x versions (maybe others).  This may be caused by a combination of your JAX-WS version being used and the server your calling.  In my case the server did not support chunked HTTP requests and JBoss WS had some bugs with dealing with that.  Here is the code I needed to add before the actual request:

```
    // HACK: This is a hack for disabling chunked encoding. .NET server run by service host does nto seem to support chunked encoding. 
    //Jboss WS version 3.0.5 has multiple bugs disallowing the setting of either a new client type or disabling chunking. 
    //So, we are resporting to this hack here.
    // This essentially sets the chunck size to 0 forcing the Webservice client to not chunk requests and not expect responses to be chunked (effectively HTTP 1.0 mode)

    //      ((StubExt) port).setConfigName("HTTP 1.0 Client"); // does not work in Jboss WS 3.0.5

    EndpointMetaData endpointMetaData = ((StubExt) serviceEndPoint).getEndpointMetaData();
    CommonConfig commonConfig = endpointMetaData.getConfig();
    boolean hacked = false;
    try {
        if (commonConfig.getProperties() != null){
            Iterator<EndpointProperty> iter = commonConfig.getProperties().iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()){
                EndpointProperty p = iter.next();
                if (p.name.equals(new URI(EndpointProperty.CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE))){
                    p.value = "0";
                    hacked = true;
                    log.info("Chunking set to 0 since service host does not support chunked requests");
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!hacked)commonConfig.addProperty(EndpointProperty.CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE, "0");
    // END HACK
```